# Nuxt server api import function with dynamic filename not working

Tags: javascript, nuxt.js, dynamic-import

In Nuxt server api, I want to import a static json file, from the assets folder, with a dynamic name

```
export default defineEventHandler(async (event) => {
  const query = getQuery(event)
  const path = query.path as keyof typeof FilePaths

  enum FilePaths {
    "home" = "../../assets/json/home.json",
    "article-1" = "../../assets/json/article-1.json",
    "article-2" = "../../assets/json/article-2.json",
    "article-3" = "../../assets/json/article-3.json",
    "article-4" = "../../assets/json/article-4.json",
    "article-5" = "../../assets/json/article-5.json",
    "article-6" = "../../assets/json/article-6.json",
  }

  const filePath = FilePaths[path]
  const page = await import(filePath, { assert: { type: 'json' } })
})
```

And I get this error

`[nuxt] [request error] [unhandled] [500] Module "file:///D:/folder/assets/json/article-1.json" needs an import assertion of type "json"`

It works if I pass the hardcoded string

`await import("../../assets/json/article-1.json")`

But don't work with a variable, or a concatenated string

How can I do it dynamically? I don't want to import all of the files, or hardcode them paths

I tried:

- specify possible filenames
- add assert option as error says

Answer (score 0):

I've managed it by using fs.readFile

```js
export default defineEventHandler(async (event) => {
  const query = getQuery(event)
  const path = query.path

  const fs = await import('fs')
  const jsonPromise = new Promise((res, rej) => {
    fs.readFile(
      `./assets/json/${path}.json`, 
      (err, data) => {
        if (err) {
          rej(err)
          throw err
        }

        const dataString = data.toString('utf-8')
        const dataJson = JSON.parse(dataString)
        res(dataJson)
      }
    )
  })

  const page = await jsonPromise

  return page
})
```

Is there a better solution?

Comment: You can use fs promises `import { promises as fs } from 'fs'` then,  
`await fs.readFile('file.txt')`. also, you should consider use `try` and `catch` in case that the file doesn't exist